# python setuptools return exit code 0 even if fail

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

I am using python 3.5 and noticed that python setuptools would return exit code 0 even if the package compilation fails. What I did is simply `python setup.py bdist_egg` and then check the exit code `echo $?`. The stdout showed syntax errors in compilation but the exit code is 0. Is this expected in setuptools? If this is the case, what's the typical way to catch the package compilation error in a bash script?

Here is an example:

```
#setup.py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="HelloWorld",
    version= '0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

There is Hello directory, which only contains `hello.py` and `__init__.py`
The **init**.py has just one line "1 + ".  This line produces syntax error as expected. when I run `python setup.py bdist_egg` , I do see the expected syntax error on stdout:

```
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Hello/hello.py to hello.cpython-36.pyc
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/Hello/hello.py", line 1
    1 +
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, when I check the return code `echo $?`, it showed 0.  Is this an expected behavior of setuptools by design? If so, how can I know in a shell script that the package is sucessfully built or fails?

**Update**
This is a known issue and it has been discussed in a github issue https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1637 though it seems that not many people care about it.

Comment: Can you show an example? [mcve]